# Classical mechanics: Hamiltonian perturbation theory. What if the perturbing parameter is < 0?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, complex-systems

In Hamiltonian Perturbation theory, we have a Hamiltonian of the form $$H(q,p) = H_0(q,p) + \lambda H_1(q,p).$$

One proceeds by expanding the equations of motion in powers of $\lambda$, assuming $\lambda \ll 1$. These expansions rely on derivatives like $\frac{dp}{d\lambda}$, evaluated at $\lambda = 0$. **My question is this: suppose for the perturbing Hamiltonian it only makes sense if $\lambda$ is greater than or equal to 0. Isn't the derivative at zero therefore undefined?** I.e., negative lambda is unphysical for the Hamiltonian system of interest (i.e., a gravitating system for which $H_1$ is the potential, and $\lambda < 0$ behaves as if there is negative mass). Are perturbative methods still valid?

Comment: I don't think one typically takes derivatives of $p$ or $q$ with respect to $\lambda$ - the only functional dependence of anything on $\lambda$ is the linear dependence in $H$, so there shouldn't be any problems at $\lambda=0$ from either side. Maybe you want to ask: is there a way to constrain perturbation theory to *make* the derivative undefined at $\lambda=0$ or *make* the system unphysical at $\lambda<0$?

Comment: Analytic continuation and "hope for the best" (in all seriousness though, the expansion w.r.t. your parameter does not rely on physical principles. Even if e.g. imaginary time doesnt make sense, we still like to use it. And so is a negative mass)

Comment: It makes sense as a formal perturbative series in $\lambda$. Convergence is another matter. Do you have a specific Hamiltonian in mind?